# Two recipient with different scenario

Tags: docusignapi

**Scenario:** Single document should be sent to two recipients, the 1'st recipient can only edit the fields and the 2'nd recipient has all the access.

Can anyone let me know, is there any possibilities that 1'st recipient can have only edit field access ( should not have sign access ) and other recipient should be able to edit fields and add sign in a single document in DocuSign.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently seven different types of recipients you can use in your DocuSign transactions. See more information [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/recipients#types)

The DocuSign platform supports many different tab types and features. You can add signature, initial and information tabs to help your signers know precisely what actions you want them to take, where in the document you want them to sign, initial or add information, and in what order. You can also do things like pre-populate tabs with data, use calculated or conditional fields, and much more.
See more information [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/stick-etabs)